# Missing characters in my URXVT

Tags: fonts, unicode, rxvt

Here is rxvt-unicode-256color side by side with xfce4-terminal printing out 
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`

[image]

What's wrong?

This happens with or without a .Xresources file

Comment: I'd assume that something broke the "fixed" font on your system (which would be the default).

Comment: This is completely a *random guess* but once upon a time I had a similar issue with `urxvt`'s internal composite.  Does this still happen if you explicitly set: `URxvt*.transparent:  false`?